# How can I dynamically get the connector table name of a Many-To-Many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

Unfortunately I have a situation where I have to write a raw SQL query. I have a model that will have many Many-to-Many relationships and I'm trying to do a generic function to get the correct information in a query.

Each of the many-to-many relationships will be setup with something along the lines of `shared = models.ManyToManyField(SharedResource)`. In my raw query function, I'm given the model that has this defined, and need to build the table name to do the raw join.

**How can I reliably get the Many-To-Many connector table name?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name for a model is available via `Model._meta.db_table`, and you can get to the through table for an M2M field via `Model.field.through`. So, in your case:

```
MyModel.shared.through._meta.db_table
```

Comment: Did you verify that `_meta` is now part of the public API? It certainly follows the private API naming convention of Python, but I *think* I remember reading a post many months ago that they were considering supporting `_meta` as part of the public API. Is this the case now? If so, can you provide a reference? Otherwise, this would probably not be a good recommendation.

Comment: It is; a GSoC student did a lot of work in the run-up to the 1.8 release to make it so. That said, not all of the attributes are documented, and `db_table` is one that isn't. It hasn't changed since well before 1.0 though so I doubt it is likely to change any time soon.

Comment: Fair enough. I think a 'disclaimer' note regarding those details should be included as part of your response, to make sure the OP knows full well in advance what he/she is getting into.